# Camera Intent Failing after provider

Tags: android, file, camera

i just launch the camera, save the uri of the image , create a file , i do everything but i keep getting a crash (if i put to select the image from gallery all works fine, but when i try to take a pic the app just crash)

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

          mImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(getContext(), this);

        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                mImageUri = result.getUri();
                mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                StorageReference filePath = mStorageUsers.child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

                mProgress.setMessage("Estableciendo foto de perfil ...");
                mProgress.setCancelable(false);
                mProgress.show();

                filePath.putFile(mImageUri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")  Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                                if (downloadUri != null) {
                                    mDatabaseUsers.child("profile_picture").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
                                }

                                mProfileImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);

                                mProgress.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                mProgress.dismiss();

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), e.getClass().getSimpleName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {

                Exception error = result.getError();
                error.getMessage();
            }

        }

    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        if (permsRequestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "BIEN!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                cameraIntent();
            }

        }

    }

    private void requestPerms() {

        String[] perms = {"android.permission.CAMERA", "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), perms, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void cameraIntent(){

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                        "com.app.appexample.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }

        }


       /* Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);*/


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

ERROR LOGCAT

> 06-14 18:58:27.338 4291-4291/com.app.appexample E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: com.app.appexample, PID: 4291
>                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity
>   {com.app.appexample/com.app.appexample.FragmentMain}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri must be non null or empty
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4094)
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4137)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri must be non null or
>   empty
>                                                                         at
>   com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage.activity(CropImage.java:358)
>                                                                         at
>   com.pholy.pholyapp.presentation.feed_user_images.view.PerfilFragment.onActivityResult(PerfilFragment.java:233)
>                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
>                                                                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6931)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4090)
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4137) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

i dont know why is happening, i have everything setup correctly

launching camera ( works , but after take the pic the app crashes)

```
mProfileImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), "android.permission.CAMERA") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    cameraIntent();

                } else {
                    requestPerms();
                }


            }
        });
```

LOGCAT ERROR POINTS TO THIS

```
 CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(getContext(), this);
```

Comment: in my manifest is good the provider, with the same name and everything, also the xml file_paths is good too, just getting an error after accepting the picture

Comment: As we discussed previously, `data.getData()` **is supposed to return `null`**. Since you are including `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, the photo should be saved at that location. So, keep track of the `File` where the photo should be, and use that. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) for how to do this.

Comment: sorry but im not seeing it

Comment: It is very difficult for people to help you when your comments are short and unclear. Instead of using `mImageUri` (which will be `null`), use `photoFile`. This is illustrated in [the sample app that I linked to in my previous comment](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider).

Comment: taking the photo is ok, the problem is here 
 mImageUri = data.getData();    if i put photoFile there how i get the data ?

Comment: "the problem is here mImageUri = data.getData();" -- correct. As I have said repeatedly, `data.getData()` will return `null`, because that is not how `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` works. "if i put photoFile there how i get the data ?" -- that depends a bit on whatever library you are using. Ideally, `activity()` takes a `File` as well as a `Uri`, so you just pass the value of `photoFile` to it. Worst-case, use `Uri.fromFile()` to create a `Uri` from the `File`, then pass that `Uri` to `activity()`. And remember to save `photoFile` across configuration changes (see the sample app).